# Azure Function File Upload and Read Content

Tags: c#, excel, azure-functions, filestream

Hello I'm trying to use Azure Function's Http trigger to receive a uploaded file and read said file.

IE.

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] 
    HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
```

The 'req' will be a file.

How can i read/parse the request?
The file will be either a text/word doc or a excel (guessing there will have to be two separate code block to handle the different media types).

EDIT: Once the file is uploaded I want to read the contents of the file: so if the file says: "Hello World" how do I read it?

Comment: this is a good example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp
Just change the row dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody); to something more useful.

Comment: Just use related package is ok. Before process, you can first get the content type of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

For example, if I have a txt file:

[image]

And I put it in the body of the request:

[image]

I will use this to get the data:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp25
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string a = req.ContentType;
            string content = null;
            if (req.ContentType == "text/plain")
            {
                content = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            }
            return new OkObjectResult(content);
        }
    }
}
```

And I will get the data:

[image]

**Orginal Answer:**

Yes, but we must first know the media types that inputs.

Just get the content type is ok.

This is the content types of common file formats:

```
.doc      application/msword
.dot      application/msword

.docx     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
.dotx     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template
.docm     application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12
.dotm     application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12

.xls      application/vnd.ms-excel
.xlt      application/vnd.ms-excel
.xla      application/vnd.ms-excel

.xlsx     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
.xltx     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template
.xlsm     application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12
.xltm     application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12
.xlam     application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12
.xlsb     application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12

.ppt      application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
.pot      application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
.pps      application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
.ppa      application/vnd.ms-powerpoint

.pptx     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
.potx     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template
.ppsx     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow
.ppam     application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12
.pptm     application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12
.potm     application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12
.ppsm     application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12

.mdb      application/vnd.ms-access
```

For more, just search the MIME types. After confirm the types of the file, just use some package to process the data.

For example, I put a docx file in the req body.

And I can do this to get the content type in C#:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp24
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string a = req.ContentType;

            return new OkObjectResult(a);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

If you need one function process different types of files, just put the logic in the body of the function to get the content type, and let different types go to different logics.

Comment: ok but how do i read/parse said file in code? ie. if the text file contains the sentence" Hello World" I want the c# code to know the content. I'm sorry if my question wasn't specific enough

Comment: @userone Hi, I have update a example about txt file. Please have a look. You just need to convert the stream to something you want.